# Выделить дату, месяц и год из строки

Tags: php

В общем ситуация такая: есть переменная и в ней дата вида `27-03-17`

```
$Date_user = preg_replace("/[^0-9-]/i", "", $_POST['Date_user']);
```

Пытаюсь уже дня два разбить дату и к числу, месяцу и году присвоить свою переменную для внесения в базу, что бы потом проводить разные манипуляции.

Пробовал через вот такие примеры с сайтов да и ещё кучу всего городил:

```
$rest = substr("abcdef", 1);
$rest = substr("abcdef", 1, 3);
$rest = substr("abcdef", 0, 4);
$rest = substr("abcdef", 0, 8);
```

или

```
$string = 'abcdef';
echo $string{0};
echo $string{3};
```

Но как итог получалось внести во все три только первое число до знака "-".

Подскажите хотя бы в какую сторону копать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов.

**Правильнее:** (Нужно использовать функции работы со временем)

```
<?php 

    // http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

    $input = "27-03-17";
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $input);
    var_dump($date->format('d'));
    var_dump($date->format('m'));
    var_dump($date->format('y'));
```

**Самый простой:**

```
<?php

    $date = "27-03-17";
    list($day, $month, $year) = explode("-", $date);

    var_dump($day, $month, $year);
```

**Сложнее:**

```
<?php 

    $date = '27-03-17';
    preg_match('/(?P<day>\d+)-(?P<month>\d+)-(?P<year>\d+)/', $date, $matches);

    var_dump($matches['day'], $matches['month'], $matches['year']);
```

Comment: спасибо, как всё просто оказалось, но сам бы в эту сторону и не подумал бы

Comment: @4ih-pqh Дополнил ответ 3-м самым правильным вариантом ;). Нужно использовать функции работы со временем.

Comment: Мне теперь что со своим делать?

Comment: @vp_arth Sorry, когда набирал не видел.

Comment: Кстати, почему split. а не explode? он ещё жив? Посмотрел - [мёртв пациент](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.split.php)

Comment: @vp_arth У меня ещё утро рано, поэтому и `split`...

Answer (score 3):

Правильный способ:

```
$input = '27-03-17';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $input);
echo $date->format('d')."\n"; // 27
echo $date->format('m')."\n"; // 03
echo $date->format('Y')."\n"; // 2017
echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."\n"; // 2017-03-27
```

Comment: откуда уверенность, что `$date !== false`?

Comment: @ZhukovRoman, соглашение о входящих данных. Не вижу особого смысла добавлять `if (!$date) throw new \Exception('Некорректный формат даты');`

Answer (score 2):

Ну и окончательно правильный ответ, учитывая

> присвоить свою переменную для внесения в базу

```
$input = '27-03-17';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $input)->format("Y-m-d");
// 2017-03-27
```

Comment: Да, я только сейчас заметил. Но все равно, люблю чтобы код был коротким и ясным :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strtotime('27-03-17';);

echo strftime("d", $date); //27
echo strftime("m", $date); //03
echo strftime("Y", $date); //2017
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]